# Kubernetes executor on Gitlab ERROR: Job failed: image pull failed

Tags: docker, kubernetes, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I tried to setup Kubernetes executor on Gitlab, but I have this error:

```
ERROR: Job failed: image pull failed: image pull failed for 
someprivateimage:latest, 
this may be because there are no credentials on this request.  details: 
(Error response from daemon: {"message":"Get 
https://someprivateimage/latest: denied: access forbidden"})
```

Anyone have idea why?

Answer (score 0):

You need to either:

- Have the docker daemon on your node login to the docker registry. Have a look at the [docker login](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/) docs
- Have the pod definition pull from a private registry. Take a look at these [kubernetes docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/)

If you're going to be doing this often, I recommend the first one.